# Redis for relational usecase

Tags: mongodb, redis, relational-database, database, nosql

We know that SQL in relation database provides flexibility of querying data. It's so so powerful but obviously at the cost of performance & scalability. I think in nosql databases also, the power of SQL can be leveraged. Like mongo db provides some kind of querying  capability.

What about redis? Is it a good idea to implement a SQL like wrapper library for redis leveraging the power of redis for secondary indexing as well as joining, ordering & grouping data? Will it be too expensive for redis? Obviously not all the operations are to be implemented - only most used ones like - inner / left joining, CRUD like interface, secondary indexing upto 2 or 3 levels only etc. I think if we keep the operations short & use the power of redis it will be possible. What's your thought?

It's just a thought. I would like to know if really implementing such a library will be of any use as I guess in many real life scenarios, we need the flexibility of SQL with the power of NoSQL database?